# How to use bit-level operations to convert single-precision floating-point numbers to integers

Tags: c, floating-point, bit, twos-complement

I am doing a data lab of CMU.

Here is the question

```
/* 
 * floatFloat2Int - Return bit-level equivalent of expression (int) f
 *   for floating point argument f.
 *   Argument is passed as unsigned int, but
 *   it is to be interpreted as the bit-level representation of a
 *   single-precision floating point value.
 *   Anything out of range (including NaN and infinity) should return
 *   0x80000000u.
 *   Legal ops: Any integer/unsigned operations incl. ||, &&. also if, while
 *   Max ops: 30
 *   Rating: 4
 */
```

When doing this lab, I always wanted to know whether to count a bit of the sign bit when the frac bit may overflow due to shifting. For example, whether an overflow occurred when `e = exp - bias = 31`. Can the sign bit of the resulting integer be known in advance? Or we can only know whether the sign bit of the integer is the same as the original floating-point number after the conversion is over?

---

I have tried to complete this lab

```
int floatFloat2Int(unsigned uf) {

  int TMin = 0x1 << 31; 
  int sign = uf >> 31;   
  int frac = uf & 0x007fffff;   
  int e = ((uf >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;  
  int M = frac | (0x1 << 23);

  if(e < 0) return 0;
  if(e > 31) return TMin;
  if(e > 23) M = M << (e - 23);
  else M = M >> (23-e); 

  if(!((M >> 31) ^ sign)) return M;
  else if(M >> 31) return TMin;
  else return ~M + 1;   

}
```

I am always wondering whether the line `else if(M >> 31) return TMin;` is necessary

Comment: What is your definition of CMU?

Comment: FWIW, assuming `sizeof(M) == 4`, then `if(M >> 31)` is just a convoluted way to say `if(M < 0)`

Comment: Here's an example of a value that would trigger that condition: '0x4f000000' -> `2147483648.0f`

Comment: @TomKarzes this might be a rare case where dual tagging is approriate.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Carnegie Mellon University?

Comment: You should use `unsigned` for your integer data types.  For example, if you have 32-bit integers, then the initial assignment to `TMin` overflows.  I don't think the C standard guarantees the result in that case.

Comment: The calculation of e needs to be signed.

Answer (score 0):

Despite all of the checks, it is possible to reach that point of the function with a value greater than can be represented as an integer.

Specifically, if `e` is exactly 31, there are no possible representable positive values since `2^31` is already greater than `INT_MAX`. There is, however, one single negative possible negative value: `-2^31` which is exactly `INT_MIN` : `-2147483548`. Because of this, none of the previous early outs can kick in (or can they? see below).

This is why that test happens at the bottom, right after checking the sign.

However, since `-2147483548` is also coincidentally the value for `TMin`, so replacing `if(e > 31) return TMin;` with `if(e >= 31) return TMin;` would have resulted in same thing.

Why not do it, then? Well, this is just a guess on my part, but having a branch that is both an error and a valid result at the same time is not exactly intuitive. On top of that it would be prone to creating knock-on issues if the error behavior is ever changed to an interrupt, or something else.